# How can I do asynchrous database in JavaFX

Tags: mysql, database, javafx

I have a question. How can I do asynchrous database in JavaFX. I know that exist SwingWoker but I read that I can't use this in JavaFX. I read about Task but I can do convert the result to  ObservableList but I need normal LinkedList. 
I'm trying conntect to mysql database

I know that this forum has a lot of answering about database in javafx but all results are converted to ObservableList

Thank you for all the answers.

FlightControllerTask.java

```
public class FlightControllerTask extends Task<LinkedList<Flight>>{
private final static int MAX=10000;
ArrayList<Airport> airportList=new ArrayList<>()
@Override
protected LinkedList<Flight> call() throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {  
        updateProgress(i, MAX);  
        Thread.sleep(5);  
   }  

    LinkedList<Flight> flightList = new LinkedList<>();
    Connection c ;
    c = DBConnector.connect(); 
    String SQL = "SELECT flight.idflight, airport.nameAirport, airport.nameAirport, flight.departureTime FROM flight INNER JOIN airport";
    ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);  
    while(rs.next()){  
        flightList.add(new Flight(rs.getInt("idflight"), rs.getString("flightFrom"), rs.getString("flightTo"), rs.getTime("departureTime")));       
   }  

    return flightList;
}
```

FlightControllerService

```
public class FlightControllerService extends Service<LinkedList<Flight>>{
@Override  
protected Task<LinkedList<Flight>> createTask() {  
     return new FlightControllerTask();  
}
```

}

MainController.java

```
final FlightControllerService service= new FlightControllerService();
    ReadOnlyObjectProperty<LinkedList<Flight>> flightList =service.valueProperty();
    flightList.get();
```

Comment: What has `Task` to do with `ObservableList`? You can use Task and inside it fetch results from database and store it in a `LinkedList`

Comment: I got it :) Thanks , but How I can get a values, because I need to write to the console, but this LinkedList is ReadOnlyProperty

Comment: I didn't get you. You need to return the `LinkedList` or iterate through the `LinkedList` and print the values.

Comment: I put my code. Can you see this?

Comment: Why use `ReadOnlyObjectProperty<LinkedList<Flight>> flightList =service.valueProperty();`, when you can use `LinkedList<Flight> flightList = service.getValue()`?

Comment: How can I get my LinkedList?

Comment: Your list is already in `flightList` reference. You should try to follow an example. [Try out this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm#BABCCGCI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class FlightControllerTask extends Task<LinkedList<Flight>>{
  @Override
  protected LinkedList<Flight> call() throws Exception { 
    // load data
    return data;
  }
}

// usage:
FlightControllerTask task = new FlightControllerTask();
task.setOnSucceeded(ev -> task.getValue());
new Thread(task).start();
```

Now the part with `task.getValue()` is the crucial part, with this method you can retrieve the value that was computed with the task as soon as is is ready (thus the succeeded hook).

Comment: Are you sure I can use it in Javafx? cuz it doesn"t work

Comment: Yes, that is why it its part of the JavaFX API... If you really want help, you need to explain what exactly is not working.