# JAVAFX - Unable to set text of a textfield

Tags: java, javafx

I have a "little" issue with Service usage.
The code below doesn't work: text value isn't updated in HMI but its value is correct !!?

```
public class FilterController
{
    @FXML
    private TextField       totalItemCount;

    private final Service service = new Service() {
        @Override
        protected Task createTask() 
        {
            return new Task<Void>() {
                @Override protected Void call() throws Exception {

                    int  x = (int) (Math.random() * 10000);
                    System.out.println("x = " + x);

                    try {
                        totalItemCount.setText(Integer.toString(x));
                        System.out.println("totalItemCount = " + totalItemCount.getText());
                    }
                    catch (Throwable ex)
                    {
                        System.err.println("Fail");
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        protected void failed()
        {
            super.failed();
            System.err.println("FAILED");
        }
    };

    @FXML
    public void handleFindProblemsEvent()
    {
        System.out.println("Handle Find Problems");
        service.restart();
    }
}
```

I don't have any error. Fail message isn't displayed, so I can think that job has been done but it's not the case. 
Is it a bug or a bad usage ?
Thanks for your help.

Note: I use jre1.8.0_25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaFX is a single thread GUI toolkit, so every update of a GUI component has to be done on the main application (JavaFX) thread.

What you are doing there, is trying to update a TextField from a background thread and an `IllegalStateException` will get thrown.

The `Task` and `Service` classes are meant to compute something in the background and do a GUI update afterwards.

Like explained [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480546/how-can-i-do-asynchrous-database-in-javafx/27484760#27484760) and [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646811/multithreading-in-javafx/27648312#27648312), you should create a `Task<Integer>` and return the computed value. If this succeeds, you can retrieve the value in the `succeeded()` method with `getValue()` and set the value to the `TextField`.
The `succeeded()` method is getting called from the GUI Thread, so its safe to update the `TextField` here.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't see any exception but your answer is interesting in this case because I must change the textfield at the end of this process. So in this case it's a good solution.
So ok, thread cannot do GUI so how can we do if I need to update periodically a GUI component ?

Comment: For periodic updates with a fixed interval, use a TimeLine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916640/javafx-not-on-fx-application-thread-when-using-timer/26916766#26916766

Comment: Thanks a lot for all these explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You have not called the `failed()` method anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, my description isn't complete.
For this test case, I have a button in my HMI and a textfield.
The button's action execute handleFindProblemsEvent() method which start the thread (service.restart())
The method failed() is provided in case of service's error. I don't have to call this method.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you Task is executed in its own thread so you need to sync calls to fx APIs with Platform.runLater

Comment: Can you explain more. I not sure to understand exactly why I need to use runLater in this case. In fact, in my real application, the textField totalItemCount is binded with a property (not seen here), but to reduce the problem, I used setText in place of bind mechanism.
Did you said I must use runLater for setText only ?