# How to update TableView items outside JavaFX Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, javafx

I have a table view that lists user's friends and I need to update it every 5 seconds with data that I retrieve from database.

This is the code I use:

```
Main.java
   private List<Friend> userFriends;
```

fx controller:

```
    ObservableList<FriendWrapper> friendList = FXCollections.observableList(
    new ArrayList<FriendWrapper>());

private void updateFriendList() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (Params.loggedUser != null) {
                Main.setUserFriends(Params.dao.listUserFriends(Params.loggedUser));
                friendList.clear();
                for (Friend friend : Main.getUserFriends()) {
                    friendList.add(new FriendWrapper(friend.getFriendName(), friend.getOnline(), friend.getFriendId(), friend.getWelcomeMessage()));
                }
                Params.dao.updateOnlineStatus(Params.loggedUser, 3);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000 * 5); 
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }, "updateFriendList").start();
}
```

`Friend` is database model. `FriendWrapper` is object used for table rows.

however I get `IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread` on line `friendList.clear();`

How can I change the items of TableView from a thread running in the background?

Answer (score 10):

Instead of a quick `Platform.runLater()` hack, you should probably make use of the [`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) class:

```
protected class LoadFriendsTask extends Task<List<FriendWrapper>>
{

    @Override
    protected List<FriendWrapper> call() throws Exception {

        List<Friend> database = new ArrayList<>(); //TODO fetch from DB
        List<FriendWrapper> result = new ArrayList<>();
        //TODO fill from database in result
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded() {
        getTableView().getItems().setAll(getValue());
    }

}
```

You can launch this one as a `Thread`, for example:

```
new Thread(new LoadFriendsTask()).start()
```

For further reference:

- [JavaFX - Background Thread for SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878788/javafx-background-thread-for-sql-query)
- [How can I do asynchrous database in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480546/how-can-i-do-asynchrous-database-in-javafx/)
- [Multithreading in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646811/multithreading-in-javafx/27648312)

Comment: It would probably be better, in the override of the `call` method, to define a better exception than `Exception`. Just as a quick recall, `RuntimeException` extends `Exception`, therefore catching `Exception` means you catch all unchecked exceptions as well.

Comment: @fge It is the default signature of the `Task`s `call()` method.

Comment: Which doesn't mean that you can't specify a better exception, and in fact you _should_. `Closeable` extends `AutoCloseable`, for instance, and it specifies that the exception thrown is `IOException`, not `Exception`. Or you can specify no exception at all.

Comment: @fge You are right. But catching everything also supports the `Task`s `onFailed` hook.. Depends on the use case ;)

Comment: @eckig how can I launch this in a loop with fixed time intervals?

Comment: @Asalas77 have a look at this beauty: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html

Comment: @eckig i am using java 7 so I can't use fx 8.0. Any other options?

Comment: @Asalas77 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html should work or a `TimeLine` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916640/javafx-not-on-fx-application-thread-when-using-timer/26916766#26916766). In both cases: Remember to always create a new `Task` object, as they are not reusable.

Answer (score 3):

Use this...

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
});
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29